# How to override liferay-ui tag in Liferay7

Tags: liferay-7

We need to override the liferay-ui:form tag in Liferay 7, because we want to hide some elements what are showed in the journal Article form. Our doubt is how to override the .java to override the code without use the ext-enviroment?
Thanks